# DataContext Inheritance in Behavior

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have 3 `DependencyProperties` declared in code behind of the `MainWindow`. The following code snippet is in the xaml code of the `MainWindow`:

```
<TextBlock>
    <e:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <bhv:VisibilityBehaviour>
            <mat:Matcher Value1="{Binding BOOL1}"/>
            <mat:Matcher Value1="{Binding BOOL2}"/>
            <mat:Matcher Value1="{Binding BOOL3}"/>
        </bhv:VisibilityBehaviour>
    </e:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBlock>
```

These Binding don't work. I think it's because the Behavior doesn't inherit the `DataContext` from parent Control. I know that when I use Freezable the `DataContext` is inherited but it doesn't work.

> System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=BOOL1; **DataItem=null**; target element is 'Matcher' (HashCode=59587750); target property is 'Value1' (type 'Boolean')

Why isn't the DataContext inherited?

Comment: How and esp. _when_ do you set the datacontext for this View?

Comment: I set the MainWindow as the DataContext (`DataContext = this;`) in code-behind at first line in constructor